# How to Quit Startup Application Automatically on Shutdown?

Tags: startup-applications

I have transmission as a start-up application. I use the command `transmission -m` to start it up. How can I quit transmission automatically when I'm shutting down?

The problems I'm facing is how to bring the running program to the foreground and send a quit command to it with a shell script? Or send a quit command without bringing it to the foreground?

Answer (score 0):

**For a simple way** you can create a **.bash_logout** file in your home dir that tells transmission to quit, e.g.:

```
transmission -q
```

or

```
transmission --quit
```

If the system does not run the **.bash_logout**, add it to `/etc/gdm/PostSession/Default` so it executes the logout script properly.

---

**Another way** is to add your command to the file `/etc/gdm/PostSession/Default` before the `exit 0` line.